# Clear History state without reloading in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using state props in a Link component of the react-router-dom to get some data while redirecting from a component. The value is then used to calculate something during the mounting of a component.

Now the problem is that the location.state persists and everytime the page reloads or due to some reason if my component remounts it uses this location.state values to recomputes which I dont want.

How do I clear the location.state without triggering a refreshing so that the result of the computation(using location.state value) after redirection remains and after refresh it is erased?

Component-1
....

```
<Link to={{
   pathname: "/component-2",
  state: { data: "data" }
 }}> linkname </Link>
```

....
 and let the component-2 be like

```
componentDidMount() {
 const { data } = this.props.history.location.state;
 const someValue = _.isUndefined(this.props.history.location.state) ? "someDefaultValue" : data;
 SomeTask(this.props.history.location.state.data);
```

}